# Lombok not working with Java 11 and IntelliJ

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a Spring Boot application with Java 11. I am using IntelliJ 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition). Lombok plug-in is installed and enabled in the IDE - version bundled 221.6008.13. In my pom.xml I have the maven dependency for project Lombok - version 1.18.28 with scope provided.

Annotation processing is enabled in the IDE settings. I’m using maven-compiler-plug-in.
The issue is that when I try to build the project, I have error that the getters and setters methods in my classes are not defined (I have the annotations @Getter @Setter).

I already tried with restarts, invalidate caches etc.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the Lombok annotation processor in your Maven config. You need to tell your build system to actually process the annotations, doing that only in the IDE is not enough.

Comment: I tried adding configuration - annotationProcessorPaths and the Lombok dependency inside path tag in the maven compiler plugin - still the same error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.